# converting a curl call to a faraday request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, proxy, faraday

I have the following curl request -

```
`curl --socks5 #{proxy} --connect-timeout 10 -H "Accept: application/json" #{url}`
```

I want to write a faraday request instead of a curl call. I am doing this -

```
faraday =  Faraday.new("#{url}", ssl:{verify: false} do |f|
    f.proxy "#{proxy}"
end
faraday.get
```

I am getting a reponse but the response has no body or headers. Following is the response -

```
#<Faraday::Response:0x0056075d353ad0 @on_complete_callbacks=[], @env=#<Faraday::Env @method=:get @url=#<URI::HTTP:0x0056075d358328 URL:main_url> @request=#<Faraday::RequestOptions proxy=#<Faraday::ProxyOptions uri=#<URI::HTTP:0x0056075dce69d0 URL:proxy_url>>> @request_headers={"User-Agent"=>"Faraday v0.9.2"} @ssl=#<Faraday::SSLOptions (empty)> @response=#<Faraday::Response:0x0056075d353ad0 ...>>>
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The hardest issue with the conversion to Faraday is that you need to use a SOCKS5 proxy. Faraday does not support SOCKS proxies (there is an [open pull-request for this](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/pull/485/files)).

The only way around this is to **monkey-patch Faraday to use the [`socksify` gem](http://socksify.rubyforge.org/)** which adds support for SOCKS proxies to `Net::HTTP` (the default Faraday network adapter). **The procedure is nicely described in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/shannonwells/a7be8752093cd74bc590)** and I mostly copy-paste a slightly altered version of it here.

Basically you need to follow these steps:

1. Install the `faraday` and `socksify` gems
2. Monkey-patch Faraday to support SOCKS. Put this code into a Rails initializer. Note that the patch only applies if you don't need to authenticate to the SOCKS proxy (as your `curl` command suggests). If you need proxy authentication, see the gist for a patch version supporting that. The patch is as follows:

   ```
   class Faraday::Adapter::NetHttp
     def net_http_connection(env)
       if proxy = env[:request][:proxy]
         if proxy[:socks]
           Net::HTTP::SOCKSProxy(proxy[:uri].host, proxy[:uri].port)
         else
           Net::HTTP::Proxy(proxy[:uri].host, proxy[:uri].port, proxy[:uri].user, proxy[:uri].password)
         end
       else
           Net::HTTP
       end.new(env[:url].host, env[:url].port)
     end
   end
   ```
3. Create the request. I noticed you are probably trying to make a HTTPS request so I took this into account, as well as the timeouts you have in the `curl` parameters:

   ```
   PROXY_OPTS = {
           uri:  URI.parse('https://proxy_url:1080'),
           socks: true  
       }

   SSL_OPTS = { verify: false }

   connection = Faraday.new(url: "https://example.com",
                            ssl: SSL_OPTS,
                            request: { proxy: PROXY_OPTS }) do |faraday|
     faraday.options.timeout = 10           # open/read timeout in seconds
     faraday.options.open_timeout = 10      # connection open timeout in seconds
     faraday.response :logger               # log debug info
     faraday.adapter  :net_http             # use the Net:HTTP adapter

     faraday.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'  # your custom headers
   end

   response = connection.get
   response.body
   ```

Finally, please note that ignoring peer verification (`verify: false` in the SSL options) is insecure! You should instead properly configure Faraday to use a certificate store to verify peer certificates against. This is fully documented [here](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/wiki/Setting-up-SSL-certificates).

Answer (score 3):

This is how I use faraday for a post request to get an access token from Microsoft Exchange API for example.

```
url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/#{ENV['TENANT']}/oauth2/token"

conn = Faraday.new url: url do |faraday|
  faraday.request  :url_encoded             # form-encode POST params
  faraday.response :logger                  # log requests to STDOUT
  faraday.adapter  Faraday.default_adapter  # make requests with Net::HTTP
end

response = conn.post do |req|
  req.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  req.body = {
    client_id: URI::encode(ENV['CLIENT_ID']),
    client_secret: URI::encode(ENV['CLIENT_SECRET']),
    resource: URI::encode('https://graph.microsoft.com'),
    grant_type: URI::encode('client_credentials'),
  }
  Rails.logger.info "Body #{req.body.inspect}"
end

if response.status.to_i == 200
  response_body = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(response.body)
  return response_body['access_token']
else
  return false
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks this helped me with an un-related problem. Upvoted.